# Siesta configureTransformer for Resource with parameters

Tags: swift, siesta-swift

I'm trying to configure a transformer for an endpoint with parameters.

I successfully configured transformers for endpoints that don't include any parameters. But it seems that when I try to do the same for Resource with parameters it won't work.

This is how I configure transformer:

```
var getExampleData: Resource { return resource(exampleDataEndpoint) }
configureTransformer(getExampleData) {
            try jsonDecoder.decode(ExampleDataResponse.self, from: $0.content)
}
```

And this is how I send the request:

```
Api.getExampleData.withParam("foo", "bar").addObserver(self).loadIfNeeded()
```

I get the response but it never goes thru the transformer pipeline.

```
Response:  200 ← GET http:example.com/enpoint?foo=bar
Siesta:pipeline │ [thread ᎠᏔᎼᎼ]  └╴Response after pipeline: success: 28 bytes
```

**EDIT**

Tested the `.withParam()` method on transforms that work fine and it seems like the URL has to be the same in order to Siesta transformers work, it's a bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Different query strings mean different URLs, and [different URLs mean different Siesta resources](http://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/guide/services-resources/#uniqueness):

> Note that “URL” includes the whole URL: protocol, host, path, and query string. It does not include headers, however. Different query strings? Different resources. http vs https? Different resources.

Thus:

```swift
let resource0 = Api.getExampleData
let resource1 = Api.getExampleData.withParam("foo", "bar”)
resource0 == resource1  // → false
```

So when you do this:

```swift
configureTransformer(getExampleData) { ... }
```

…that applies only to `getExampleData`, not to any variations with different params.

If you want configuration to apply to all resources that share a path, match on the path:

```swift
configureTransformer("/example/path") { ... }
```